# Rotation causes tableview to extend past safe area when using custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm having an issue when rotating a table view controller that has a custom cell. I created a simple Table View Controller and set it up as follows

```
import UIKit

class MyTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(CustomCellMain.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCellMain")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCellMain") as! CustomCellMain
        cell.mainImage = UIImage(named: "testtest.jpeg")
        cell.message = "Hello"
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }
}
```

My custom cell looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCellMain: UITableViewCell {
    var message: String?
    var mainImage: UIImage?

    var messageView: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //labelView.isScrollEnabled = false
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 27)
        return label
    }()

    var mainImageView: UIImageView = {
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.sizeToFit()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return imageView
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(mainImageView)
        self.addSubview(messageView)

        //Image
        mainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        mainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 9).isActive = true
        mainImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        mainImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
        mainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true

        //Text
        messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainImageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let message = message {
            messageView.text = message
        }
        if let image = mainImage {
            mainImageView.image = image
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

It looks fine vertically:

[image]

But when i rotate it, it covers up the left or right sides

[image]

[image]

I can't figure out what is causing this. Any help would be super appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve it using `Main.Storyboard`**

- Go to `Main.Storyboard`
- Select Your `UITableView`
- Go to it's `Size Inspector`
- In that Checkmark the option of `Content View [TickMark] Insets To Safe Area`

**If that doesn't work then try `Content Insets` drop down menu options**

- Sometime `never` or `automatic` option work in it.

**OR**

- try `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` in your custom cell file
- In Main.Storyborad , select your cell and give it `Translate Mask Into Constraints` in Layoutdropdown in SizeInspector

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those options helped :(

Comment: I've edited my answer , please check it and get back :)

Comment: have you considered turning off rotation ?? or do you want to show rotation anyhow ???

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a View Controller with Table View instead. This fixed the issue. I think because I couldn't constrain the actual table view to the safe area it was going outside (with the custom view being bigger than the table view).